# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data' or one of its dependencies

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

After exploring enough I've decided to post this question here. I'm facing this error in my WebApi project which is working very well on local IIS but when I deployed my project on my Live Server I'm facing this issue  **Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data' or one of its dependencies**. I'm working with MySql Database and added all the related dependencies in web.config file but nothing seems to be working out for me.

my **Web.Config** file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--  
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
      -->
    <configuration>
      <configSections>  
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-IntranetApiDemo-20180709022909.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-IntranetApiDemo-20180709022909;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />        
<add name="DBCS" connectionString="Server=14.192.18.129;userid=admin;password=pwd; Database=db; convert zero datetime=True; default command timeout=0; SslMode = none" providerName="System.Data.MySqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <appSettings></appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules>
          <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
          <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
          <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>  
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-6.10.7.0" newVersion="6.10.7.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>    
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <entityFramework>
       <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
                type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.7.0"/>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
                type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
      <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
          <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
          <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
      </system.codedom>
    </configuration>
```

As you can see in my code above the verion of MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 **(Version=6.10.7.0)**  matches with the MySql.Data.MySqlClient **Version =6.10.7.0**.

Is there anything which is missing in Web.Config file.
Please help me to solve this problem.

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should not only set assembly binding redirection for `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` namespace, but also includes its parent namespace i.e. `MySql.Data`:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-6.10.7.0" newVersion="6.10.7.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

**Note:** Before using this binding redirection, make sure `MySql.Data.dll` assembly (and all its dependencies) in the production server exists & has its version matches with installed version in your development machine (6.10.7.0).

Additionally, the connection string provider for MySQL should have `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` provider like this:

```
<add name="DBCS" connectionString="Server=14.192.18.129;userid=admin;password=pwd; Database=db; convert zero datetime=True; default command timeout=0; SslMode=none" 
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Reference:

[MySQL Entity Framework 6 Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a mismatch with the installed MySQL.Data version. You can also change the dependentAssembly web.config settings. Match the newVersion with the version you're using. If it's backward compatible, see also: [Microsoft Redirecting Assemlby Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions)